# PHP - How do you find files with the same numerical prefix and store them in an array

Tags: php

I have a directory of images and I need to be able to scan through the directory and find files with the same numerical prefix and store them in a list/array

---

**images/** 
1a.jpg
1b.jpg
1c.jpg
2a.jpg
2b.jpg
.
.
.
10a.jpg
10b.jpg
.
.
.
100a.jpg
100b.jpg
100c.jpg
.
etc.

---

**Desired outcome after function**

**list "1"**
1a.jpg
1b.jpg
1c.jpg
.
.
.
**list "2"**
2a.jpg
2b.jpg
.
.
.
**list "10"**
10a.jpg
10b.jpg
.
.
.
**list "100"**
100a.jpg
100b.jpg
100c.jpg
.
etc.

---

from what I've gobbled up in my research. I'm guessing it should go something like this:

```
<?php   
    // find image files starting with number prefix(1,2...10...100...etc)

    foreach (glob("1*.jpg") as $filename) {
        echo "$filename";
    }
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:
1a.jpg
1b.jpg
1c.jpg

But How do I run this function for all files in my directory? (1a.jpg, 2a.jpg, 3a.jpg... 24a.jpg.. 112a.jpg, 112b.jpg)

Comment: `(int)'100a.jpg' === 100`, it should help you.

Comment: "i need to" is not a question, it's just your requirement. What specific problem are you having in achieving this? What did you research or try for yourself before asking others for help?

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) php function, seems to fit your needs.

```
glob("images/1[a-z].jpg");
glob("images/10[a-z].jpg");
//example for your need 1 followed by everything but not a number :
glob("images/1[^0-9]*.jpg");
```

Comment: Updated, you may use better patterns than *